# Interrupt handling in linux. Interrupts sharing

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

Here's my question. Manuals say: "when the kernel receives an interrupt, all the registered handlers are invoked." And I wonder if there is any rule, specifying an order in which handlers will be invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel function `request_irq` calls `setup_irq` (in `kernel/irq/manage.c`).  They are chained in the order they were associated with the IRQ.  That is, each ISR is added to the end of the list.

Comment: And now I've gon another question. Is it possible to make system to call my hanвler first and only than call default. (for example my handler works, than it just doesnt clear the interruptin bit, so to make system call the next one which is default)? Maybe I can change the order of handlers in chain you told me about.

Comment: @Farrel:  If your code has access to the kernel structures, you could reorder the chain.  But why?  The latency to activate the ISR depends on many system factors, not just the order of the chain.

Comment: @wallyk then how it is handled in case of shared interrupts. I understand that we define devid for differentiating between the devices sharing interrupts but when the Interrupt comes, how the search for the required irq handler is done?

Comment: @0x07FC:  I think there is a chain per IRQ vector.  The IRQ handler looks at each entry on the chain and decides to call the driver (or maybe not).  The driver handler then needs to determine if it needs to do anything.  In either case (handling the interrupt or not) it returns and the IRQ handler goes on to the next entry in the chain.

Comment: in that case, how devid is used to differentiate between different devices for same irq line?